# Clear contents on original sheet after copying/pasting

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this script to copy and paste rows from the original sheet to the archive sheet that have been confirmed to have been actioned on - which works perfectly! But I also want to clear the contents on the original sheet so it does not copy duplicate rows. I'm new to writing script and would appreciate all suggestions!

```
   function moveValuesOnly(){
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Time Off Action Items");
     var range = ss.getRange("A3:K");
     var values = range.getValues();
     var target = new Array();
      for(i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
      if (values[i][9] == "Confirm"){
      target.push(values[i])
     }
     }

   var sDest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Archive");
   sDest.getRange(sDest.getLastRow()+1,1,target.length,target[0].length).setValues(target);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a similar sheet for a work project, and the solution I came up with was to store the values of the rows as I copied them to a new array and then deleted the rows from the bottom up using a for loop. For your instance, try this:

```
function moveValuesOnly(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Time Off Action Items");
  var range = ss.getRange("A3:K");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var target = new Array();
  // Create new array to log copied rows
  var copiedRows = new Array();
  for(i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
    if (values[i][9] == "Confirm"){
      target.push(values[i]);
      // Add row value into copied rows array
      copiedRows.push(i);
    }
  }
  var sDest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Archive");
  sDest.getRange(sDest.getLastRow()+1,1,target.length,target[0].length).setValues(target);
  // Go back through and delete rows from the bottom up
  var totalCopied = copiedRows.length;
  for (s = totalCopied; s>0; s--) {
  ss.deleteRow(copiedRows[s-1]+3);
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much! Would it be able to clear the contents on that row instead of deleting it altogether? I just realized that the original sheet pulls from a filter formula so it brings the row back after the script works.

Comment: I'm also seeing an issue where the script will sometimes not copy the full row but only the last couple of columns. Do you see anything in this script that would cause that to happen?

Comment: @DanaeGonzales make sure you take a look at [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) and [clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear) so you know which one you want to use. Then just change `ss.deleteRow(copiedRows[s-1]+3);` to `ss.getRange(copiedRows[s-1]+3,1,1,11).clear();` or `ss.getRange(copiedRows[s-1]+3,1,1,11).clearContents();`

As far as it only copying the last couple columns, nothing should be causing that. Try putting a logger in `Logger.log(variable)` to see where it happens.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Wilco! As of now the second issue hasn't come up again but if it does i'll try to dissect the script and see where the issue lies. Thanks again for all your help!